# How do I beat Orthros in Bravely Default?

Tags: bravely-default

Well, I'm having problems with Orthros.

The average level in my party 16.

I've tried going with 2 mages/2 healers, or 1 knight, 2 mages and 1 healer.

This is how my attempts tend to go like:

- Battle begins
- The first one to act is my healer. I normally use shell on the party (using brave).
- The second one to act is always Orthros:

  - First head uses either blazzard or an area of effect spell. Heavy damage.
  - Second head uses either blazzard or an area of effect spell. Heavy damage.
  - RARELY they use a physical attack - which is a miracle. Almost always they use magic.
- Orthros' attacks have a decent chance to critical strike. If this happens, one or even two of my party members will die (usually the healers/mages). At this point, the party loses its sustain members, and Orthros will finish killing it in the next turns. Reviving the dead healers/mages is not very efficient: I need to spend several Braves to fully heal them, because if I don't heal them immediately, the 200HP from the Phoenix Down won't be enough for them to survive the next AoE attack from Orthros.
- If, miraculously, the healers survive the first turn, I have them heal the whole party.
- Any other living member will focus attack one head.
- Next, it is Orthros' turn again. Chances of surviving another wave of AoE attacks are pretty dim. I can't last many turns against him (I can't even kill one head).

The general advice in the web is to always have a positive Brave meter, and focus all your attacks on one head. Still, the continuous AoE attacks from Orthros are too strong for the party and it can't survive much. If he doesn't critical, there is some chance, but if he does (and it happens decently often), then for sure someone will die.

Am I too low level for Orthros? What else am I supposed to do?

I am playing in normal difficulty (and don't really want to change the setting).

Comment: When playing on normal I found that most bosses could simply be beaten by braving 4 times using a special on each character and 3 offensive moves (you can even get away with some semi offensive moves like mug) and killing them in a single turn. This worked through all of my normal game. On hard it stopped being as effective around the earth crystal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a trick to Orthos - if you use an opposing element on a head (fire on ice, ice on fire), that head will 'shut down', making it unable to use any elemental attacks and switching to physical. It also eliminates the possibility of using Blazzard, because that requires both heads to be 'active'. This state lasts about 3 turns, after which (or during the third, I'm not sure), it will re-activate, possibly casting its element's AOE. Because of this, never disable both heads at the same time, always go for one first and the other a turn or two later. This way Orthos will be completely unable to use Blazzard, as long as you keep disabling the heads again and again.

My suggestion would be to have your healer (or whoever will go first) use an offensive item (either fire or ice, you should have at least one by now) and then just let a black mage to roll with it. However, if you feel like you still aren't making any progress, try leveling up, both party members and their jobs. If you haven't done the sidequests yet, do so, they can serve as a sort of a benchmark.